# Referencing Infragistics Assembly in Visual C# 2008

Tags: c#, assemblies, infragistics

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and am trying to use the *NetAdvantage 10.2 Win CLR2x* Toolbox functions for forms (UltraButton, UltraLabel etc etc). When I try and compile the code however, I get the following errors:

> *The type 'Infragistics.Shared.IUltraLicensedComponent' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'Infragistics2.Shared.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.2035,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'.
>   C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\InfragisticsTest\InfragisticsTest\Form1.Designer.cs
>
> The type 'Infragistics.Win.IImageListProvider' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Infragistics2.Win.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.2035, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'.    C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\InfragisticsTest\InfragisticsTest\Form1.Designer.cs
>
> The type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Infragistics2.Win.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.2035, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'.    C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\InfragisticsTest\InfragisticsTest\Form1.Designer.cs*

I believe this may have been caused by installing visual studio 2012, then reverting back to 2008. But I am unsure as to how to fix this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have correctly added the Infragistics2.Win.v10.2, Infragistics2.Shared.v10.2 and of course Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.v10.2 assemblies in your project references list?

Comment: How would I reference this?
"using Infragistics;"?

Comment: Expand the project node in Solution Explorer, expand References and check if there is any error, remove the wrong references and readd the correct ones right-clicking on the References item.

Comment: Thanks Steve, great solution, add that as an answer and I will +1 it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message point to some kind of problem in the references of your current project.
Usually this means that the Visual Studio IDE could not resolve one or more items in the references list because incompatibilities or other subtle changes in the referenced assemblies.

As a rule of thumb you should expand the project node in `Solution Explorer`, then expand the `References` node and check if there are errors, remove the wrong references and re-add the correct ones right-clicking on the References item and searching for them through the GAC or some path in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Infragistics products before and my experience is that they depend heavily on their installers. All the problems I ever had with them were solved by completely uninstalling the Infragistics product and installing it again.

Comment: Due to license complications, I needed to find a solution that did not involve reinstalling. Thanks anyway!